# Using monomorphic functions with polymorphic Haxl library?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, monomorphism, haxl

I'm using the Haxl library and I'm trying to implement `fetchHTML` concurrently:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent.QSem
import Haxl.Core
import Haxl.Prelude

instance DataSource' u HTTPRequest where 
  fetch = metaImplementation

data HTTPRequest a where
  MakeRequest :: HTTPRequest Int

instance StateKey HTTPRequest where --Link HTTPRequest to State class
   data State HTTPRequest =
    HTTPRequestState {threadNum :: Int}

initialiseState :: Int -> IO (State HTTPRequest)
initialiseState threads = do
   return HTTPRequestState {threadNum = threads}

metaImplementation :: State HTTPRequest -> Flags -> u -> [BlockedFetch' HTTPRequest] -> PerformFetch 
metaImplementation HTTPRequestState{..} _flags user bfs =
AsyncFetch $ \inner -> do
    sem <- newQSem threadNum
    asyncs <- mapM (implementation sem) bfs
    inner
    mapM_ wait asyncs

implementation :: QSem -> BlockedFetch' HTTPRequest -> IO(Async())
implementation sem (BlockedFetch' request returnVal) = 
   async $ bracket_ (waitQSem sem) (signalQSem sem) $ do
      e <- Control.Exception.try $ 
         fetchHTML
      case e of 
        Left ex -> putFailure returnVal (ex :: SomeException)
        Right el -> putSuccess returnVal el


fetchHTML :: IO Int
fetchHTML = do
    res <- get "https://example.com"
    let resBody = res ^. responseBody 
    return (200)

makeHTTPRequest :: GenHaxl u Int --Perform concurrent fetches
makeHTTPRequest = dataFetch (MakeRequest)
```

The problem I'm facing is that Haxl's `BlockedFetch` is polymorphic:

```
BlockedFetch :: forall (r :: * -> *) a.  r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r
```

Yet I wish `fetchHTML` to be monomorphic (only return an Int):

```
fetchHTML :: IO Int 
fetchHTML = do
   res <- get "https://www.bbc.com"
   let resBody = res ^. responseBody 
   return (200)
```

So I get the following error when I attempt to compile:

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
    ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      BlockedFetch :: forall (r :: * -> *) a.
                      r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r,
    in an equation for ‘implementation’
```

Initially I thought I could re-define `BlockedFetch` as so:

```
data BlockedFetch' a where --Custom monomorphic implementation of BlockedFetch 
   BlockedFetch' :: HTTPRequest Int -> ResultVar Int -> BlockedFetch' HTTPRequest
```

However, then that requires a new implementation of `DataSource`, to enable it to receive my custom `BlockFetch'`:

```
class (DataSourceName r, StateKey r) => DataSource' u r where 
   fetch :: State r -> Flags -> u -> [BlockedFetch' r] -> PerformFetch
```

**Clearly, this will just affect backwards and require me to re-write the entire Haxl module!**

My questions are:

1) Is there a simple way to make `fetchHTML` polymorphic? (I'm not too concerned about what it returns, just it returns *something* when it's finished)

2) What is the general approach by Haskell programmers when faced with this sort of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `BlockedFetch` constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl-0.5.0.0/docs/src/Haxl-Core-Types.html#BlockedFetch) existentially quantifies `a`:

```
data BlockedFetch r = forall a. BlockedFetch (r a) (ResultVar a)
```

This means that whoever creates a `BlockedFetch` gets to choose what `a` is, but upon unpacking a `BlockedFetch` `a` is kept abstract and won't unify with anything else.

However, you do get access to the `r` type. By choosing `r` to be a GADT you can constrain `a` to be (one of a set of) particular type(s), and recover that information by matching on the constructor(s) of your GADT. You don't have to rewrite any Haxl code - it was designed to allow you to plug in your own `r`!

In this instance, I see that you've already got 90% of the way there:

```
data HttpRequest a where
    MakeRequest :: HttpRequest Int
```

So when you match on the `MakeRequest` constructor you gain the knowledge that `a ~ Int`.

```
implementation :: QSem -> BlockedFetch' HTTPRequest -> IO(Async())
                               -- match the MakeRequest constructor
implementation sem (BlockedFetch' MakeRequest returnVal) =
    -- as before
```

Comment: @BabraCunningham No: you wrote down version which attempted to match a parameter inside the `MakeRequest` constructor (you had `(BlockedFetch' (MakeRequest int) returnVal)`. `MakeRequest` is a nullary constructor.

Comment: I see! I've changed implementation to `implementation sem (BlockedFetch (MakeRequest) returnVal) =`... was this what you meant by "match on the MakeRequest" ?